# DNS only works when domain prefixed with https://

Tags: domain-name-system, https, godaddy

I bought the domain `example.com` (of course, that is not the real name of my domain) from GoDaddy (I doubt that the fact that it is through GoDaddy is relevant, but I do not know).

When I type `example.com` into the address bar of my browser, I see this:

[image: website coming soon!]

When I type `https://example.com` into the address bar, I get my site's homepage (although it takes a very long time - maybe the issue of time is related?).

How do I make it so that I can type in `example.com` or `https://example.com`  into my address bar and
automatically get to my site?

This is what my DNS records look like right now:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your web server configuration so that both `http://www.example.com` makes a 301 redirect to `https://www.example.com`, and you need to make sure that `https://www.example.com` provides the proper content.

Answer (score 0):

Domain Names has no thing to do with the HTTP protocol or HTTPS

The main purpose of a DNS server is to map a name to an IP address that's all

If you issue the command `nslookup example.com` or `nslookup www.example.com` you'll see the mapping  between theses names and the IP addresses

So if you want `example.com` and `www.example.com` point to the same IP address you have to ensure that the A record for @ and the A record for www point to the same location

Comment: My problem is not that `www.example.com` works different than `example.com`. My problem is that `https://example.com` works different than `example.com`.

Comment: This is a browser issue not DNS